# The limits of forgiveness

Tags: forgiving-mechilah

Over the years I read suggestions that we should forgive Germany, Poland, Russia, the Catholic Church, the Crusades, Christianity, Islam, Egypt, the Ku Klux Klan, etc.

The only "forgiveness" I ever found in the Sources was forgiveness of an individual, by God or by another individual.  I never found any mention of "forgiveness" of a country, an institution, a religion, or any group of people as a whole.  Is there such a concept in Judaism?

There are hints of that (such as "Do not despise an Edomite, because he is your brother. Do not despise an Egyptian, because you resided as foreigners in his  country." [Deut. 23:7]), but it does not rise to "forgiveness".

Comment: When you say "I read" do you mean "in Jewish religious sources", because asking "I read in a local newspaper" sounds weak?

Comment: "country, an institution, a religion," are all people, just as Judaism is all about single Rabbis, there's no "institution" or "religion". You can't forgive Judaism also.

Comment: *forgiveness* requires acknowledgement of the sin and a request for forgiveness. That requires an individual at both ends.

Comment: I don't understand what this notion of forgiveness of an institution that you're asking about is. Forgiveness of its deeds? It has no deeds: only its members do. Forgiveness of its monetary debts? Yes, it could have debts, but if that's what you mean you should [edit] the question to say so, as it's unclear.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sunflower:_On_the_Possibilities_and_Limits_of_Forgiveness#List_of_responses

Comment: We can forgive the Egyptians, Spaniards, Poles, Russians, etc, but must never forget nor forgive the Nazis.

Comment: @Silver. Very interesting.  Thank you.  Not a single Jew voted to forgive.  (But I still want to know if Judaism even HAS a group forgiveness provision.)

Comment: Would not the kohen gadol ask for forgiveness on behalf of Klal Yisroel and on behalf of all the Kohanim on Yom Kippur? We see such a concept exists, although perhaps it is something only Hashem is capable of doing

Comment: @Jonathan Not to belittle the enormous tragedy that is the Holocaust, but why do you draw the line there? Why do you feel that the Nazis are unforgivable, but the Spaniards are? (For the record, I have relatives who went through the Holocaust, as well as ones who went through the Inquisition.)

Comment: @DonielF -- Good point.  I, too, have relatives in just about all victimized Jewish communities, and I don't forgive any GROUPS.  Individuals who sound sincere is another matter.  And I tell them that if they personally did not murder or harass Jews, they have nothing to be forgiven for.

Comment: @DonielF Obviously, the Inquisition was a terrible thing, especially 1492, but it cannot be compared to the Holocaust (Shoah) because the Holocaust killed 6 million Jews. I personally, will never forgive the nazis and thank G-d they are in hell.

Comment: @Jonathan So where is your line? I don’t disagree that the Nazis were despicable creatures, but why are the Spaniards forgivable for their atrocities?

Comment: @DonielF The Spaniards were awful people, no doubt. But the Nazis were far worse.

Comment: @Jonathan You’re dodging my question. I don’t deny how horrid the Nazis were; I’m asking why you feel the Spaniards are forgivable.

Comment: The Inquisition was a long time ago. And the Spanish government asked forgiveness.

Comment: @Jonathan I *think* DonielF wants to know (more or less) is it the number, kind of crime, length of time since the crime (etc.) that makes it unforgivable; and if so, which specifically, and from what source do you derive that 'doctrine' of forgiveness (i.e. the number, kind of crime, length of time since its commission, etc.), not whether you personally think Nazis are worse than Spaniards or the Inquisition.

Comment: @SolaGratia I do think, personally, that the Nazis were worse than the Spaniards. I would add that the length of time accounts for part of my conviction yet, I would caution this same reaction in regards to the holocaust. I would also add that many Spaniards had asked forgiveness since then. Although Germany has paid reparations they are still many denials, especially within the young german community who cannot imagine that their grandfathers committed crimes against humanity.

Comment: I would also add that the Christians were acting out in the word of their gods while the Nazis were acting for the sake of evil and vengeance. The annihilation of six million Jews was the cause of evil.

Comment: The Inquisition is not relevant to the answering of DonielF's line of question, nor are Nazis, I don't think. The issue is more whether then you think it is whether the offender asks for forgiveness (or is it lack of asking for forgiveness plus x amount of gravity + y length of time)? This is still unclear to me. By the way, as a Christian, no Christian group believes in 'gods.' The main Creed of Christendom begins, "We believe in one God: the Father almighty" I.e. what is the specific, not vague, reason Nazis are unforgivable and Spaniards not.